# Print command not showing anything in jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am using jupyter notebook and it seems like the print function is not working:

The commands are as follows:

```
In [1]: 'hello world'
Out [1]: 'hello world'

In [2]: print 'hello world'
```

print statement is not printing anything.
Does anyone know whether it's a known bug?

Answer (score -1):

Use `print('Hello World')` instead. 
Print is a function in Python 3.